# How do I change the letters of the keyboard without using X?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, console

In Linux, can I remap the keyboard keys, but without using the *X* commands?

Using `xmodmap`, I can change the number *1* by the letter *Q*:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode   10 = q Q q Q bar exclam bar exclamdown"
```

How do I do this, but without using *X* commands?

I do not want to use *X* because I want to use it in the console, before starting *Xorg*.

Also, I would like to be able to activate the Bloqnum from the console, but with `numlockx` the *Xorg* is necessary.

---

The `loadkeys` program does not work for me. The script I did was the following (**/mnt/sda2/a**):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

echo "keymaps 0-255
keycode  16 = w               
keycode  17 = q               " > /mnt/sda2/b
loadkeys -v /mnt/sda2/b
```

With this, what I want to achieve is that by pressing *1*, the *W*. appears, and when pressing the *2*, the *Q*. appears.

The following message appears, but when pressing the keys, I do not see the change:

```bsh
> /mnt/sda2/a

Loading /mnt/sda2/b
keycode 16, table 0 = 2935
keycode 17, table 0 = 2929
keycode 16, table 1 = 2903
keycode 17, table 1 = 2897
keycode 16, table 2 = 2935
keycode 17, table 2 = 2929
keycode 16, table 3 = 2903
keycode 17, table 3 = 2897
keycode 16, table 4 = 23
keycode 17, table 4 = 17
keycode 16, table 5 = 23
keycode 17, table 5 = 17
keycode 16, table 6 = 23
keycode 17, table 6 = 17
keycode 16, table 7 = 23
keycode 17, table 7 = 17
keycode 16, table 8 = 2167
keycode 17, table 8 = 2161
keycode 16, table 9 = 2135
keycode 17, table 9 = 2129
keycode 16, table 10 = 2167
keycode 17, table 10 = 2161
keycode 16, table 11 = 2135
keycode 17, table 11 = 2129
keycode 16, table 12 = 2071
keycode 17, table 12 = 2065
keycode 16, table 13 = 2071
keycode 17, table 13 = 2065
keycode 16, table 14 = 2071
keycode 17, table 14 = 2065
keycode 16, table 15 = 2071
keycode 17, table 15 = 2065
keycode 16, table 16 = 2935
keycode 17, table 16 = 2929
keycode 16, table 17 = 2903
keycode 17, table 17 = 2897
keycode 16, table 18 = 2935
keycode 17, table 18 = 2929
keycode 16, table 19 = 2903
keycode 17, table 19 = 2897
keycode 16, table 20 = 23
keycode 17, table 20 = 17
keycode 16, table 21 = 23
keycode 17, table 21 = 17
keycode 16, table 22 = 23
keycode 17, table 22 = 17
keycode 16, table 23 = 23
keycode 17, table 23 = 17
keycode 16, table 24 = 2167
keycode 17, table 24 = 2161
keycode 16, table 25 = 2135
keycode 17, table 25 = 2129
keycode 16, table 26 = 2167
keycode 17, table 26 = 2161
keycode 16, table 27 = 2135
keycode 17, table 27 = 2129
keycode 16, table 28 = 2071
keycode 17, table 28 = 2065
keycode 16, table 29 = 2071
keycode 17, table 29 = 2065
keycode 16, table 30 = 2071
keycode 17, table 30 = 2065
keycode 16, table 31 = 2071
keycode 17, table 31 = 2065
keycode 16, table 32 = 2935
keycode 17, table 32 = 2929
keycode 16, table 33 = 2903
keycode 17, table 33 = 2897
keycode 16, table 34 = 2935
keycode 17, table 34 = 2929
keycode 16, table 35 = 2903
keycode 17, table 35 = 2897
keycode 16, table 36 = 23
keycode 17, table 36 = 17
keycode 16, table 37 = 23
keycode 17, table 37 = 17
keycode 16, table 38 = 23
keycode 17, table 38 = 17
keycode 16, table 39 = 23
keycode 17, table 39 = 17
keycode 16, table 40 = 2167
keycode 17, table 40 = 2161
keycode 16, table 41 = 2135
keycode 17, table 41 = 2129
keycode 16, table 42 = 2167
keycode 17, table 42 = 2161
keycode 16, table 43 = 2135
keycode 17, table 43 = 2129
keycode 16, table 44 = 2071
keycode 17, table 44 = 2065
keycode 16, table 45 = 2071
keycode 17, table 45 = 2065
keycode 16, table 46 = 2071
keycode 17, table 46 = 2065
keycode 16, table 47 = 2071
keycode 17, table 47 = 2065
keycode 16, table 48 = 2935
keycode 17, table 48 = 2929
keycode 16, table 49 = 2903
keycode 17, table 49 = 2897
keycode 16, table 50 = 2935
keycode 17, table 50 = 2929
keycode 16, table 51 = 2903
keycode 17, table 51 = 2897
keycode 16, table 52 = 23
keycode 17, table 52 = 17
keycode 16, table 53 = 23
keycode 17, table 53 = 17
keycode 16, table 54 = 23
keycode 17, table 54 = 17
keycode 16, table 55 = 23
keycode 17, table 55 = 17
keycode 16, table 56 = 2167
keycode 17, table 56 = 2161
keycode 16, table 57 = 2135
keycode 17, table 57 = 2129
keycode 16, table 58 = 2167
keycode 17, table 58 = 2161
keycode 16, table 59 = 2135
keycode 17, table 59 = 2129
keycode 16, table 60 = 2071
keycode 17, table 60 = 2065
keycode 16, table 61 = 2071
keycode 17, table 61 = 2065
keycode 16, table 62 = 2071
keycode 17, table 62 = 2065
keycode 16, table 63 = 2071
keycode 17, table 63 = 2065
keycode 16, table 64 = 2935
keycode 17, table 64 = 2929
keycode 16, table 65 = 2903
keycode 17, table 65 = 2897
keycode 16, table 66 = 2935
keycode 17, table 66 = 2929
keycode 16, table 67 = 2903
keycode 17, table 67 = 2897
keycode 16, table 68 = 23
keycode 17, table 68 = 17
keycode 16, table 69 = 23
keycode 17, table 69 = 17
keycode 16, table 70 = 23
keycode 17, table 70 = 17
keycode 16, table 71 = 23
keycode 17, table 71 = 17
keycode 16, table 72 = 2167
keycode 17, table 72 = 2161
keycode 16, table 73 = 2135
keycode 17, table 73 = 2129
keycode 16, table 74 = 2167
keycode 17, table 74 = 2161
keycode 16, table 75 = 2135
keycode 17, table 75 = 2129
keycode 16, table 76 = 2071
keycode 17, table 76 = 2065
keycode 16, table 77 = 2071
keycode 17, table 77 = 2065
keycode 16, table 78 = 2071
keycode 17, table 78 = 2065
keycode 16, table 79 = 2071
keycode 17, table 79 = 2065
keycode 16, table 80 = 2935
keycode 17, table 80 = 2929
keycode 16, table 81 = 2903
keycode 17, table 81 = 2897
keycode 16, table 82 = 2935
keycode 17, table 82 = 2929
keycode 16, table 83 = 2903
keycode 17, table 83 = 2897
keycode 16, table 84 = 23
keycode 17, table 84 = 17
keycode 16, table 85 = 23
keycode 17, table 85 = 17
keycode 16, table 86 = 23
keycode 17, table 86 = 17
keycode 16, table 87 = 23
keycode 17, table 87 = 17
keycode 16, table 88 = 2167
keycode 17, table 88 = 2161
keycode 16, table 89 = 2135
keycode 17, table 89 = 2129
keycode 16, table 90 = 2167
keycode 17, table 90 = 2161
keycode 16, table 91 = 2135
keycode 17, table 91 = 2129
keycode 16, table 92 = 2071
keycode 17, table 92 = 2065
keycode 16, table 93 = 2071
keycode 17, table 93 = 2065
keycode 16, table 94 = 2071
keycode 17, table 94 = 2065
keycode 16, table 95 = 2071
keycode 17, table 95 = 2065
keycode 16, table 96 = 2935
keycode 17, table 96 = 2929
keycode 16, table 97 = 2903
keycode 17, table 97 = 2897
keycode 16, table 98 = 2935
keycode 17, table 98 = 2929
keycode 16, table 99 = 2903
keycode 17, table 99 = 2897
keycode 16, table 100 = 23
keycode 17, table 100 = 17
keycode 16, table 101 = 23
keycode 17, table 101 = 17
keycode 16, table 102 = 23
keycode 17, table 102 = 17
keycode 16, table 103 = 23
keycode 17, table 103 = 17
keycode 16, table 104 = 2167
keycode 17, table 104 = 2161
keycode 16, table 105 = 2135
keycode 17, table 105 = 2129
keycode 16, table 106 = 2167
keycode 17, table 106 = 2161
keycode 16, table 107 = 2135
keycode 17, table 107 = 2129
keycode 16, table 108 = 2071
keycode 17, table 108 = 2065
keycode 16, table 109 = 2071
keycode 17, table 109 = 2065
keycode 16, table 110 = 2071
keycode 17, table 110 = 2065
keycode 16, table 111 = 2071
keycode 17, table 111 = 2065
keycode 16, table 112 = 2935
keycode 17, table 112 = 2929
keycode 16, table 113 = 2903
keycode 17, table 113 = 2897
keycode 16, table 114 = 2935
keycode 17, table 114 = 2929
keycode 16, table 115 = 2903
keycode 17, table 115 = 2897
keycode 16, table 116 = 23
keycode 17, table 116 = 17
keycode 16, table 117 = 23
keycode 17, table 117 = 17
keycode 16, table 118 = 23
keycode 17, table 118 = 17
keycode 16, table 119 = 23
keycode 17, table 119 = 17
keycode 16, table 120 = 2167
keycode 17, table 120 = 2161
keycode 16, table 121 = 2135
keycode 17, table 121 = 2129
keycode 16, table 122 = 2167
keycode 17, table 122 = 2161
keycode 16, table 123 = 2135
keycode 17, table 123 = 2129
keycode 16, table 124 = 2071
keycode 17, table 124 = 2065
keycode 16, table 125 = 2071
keycode 17, table 125 = 2065
keycode 16, table 126 = 2071
keycode 17, table 126 = 2065
keycode 16, table 127 = 2071
keycode 17, table 127 = 2065
keycode 16, table 128 = 2935
keycode 17, table 128 = 2929
keycode 16, table 129 = 2903
keycode 17, table 129 = 2897
keycode 16, table 130 = 2935
keycode 17, table 130 = 2929
keycode 16, table 131 = 2903
keycode 17, table 131 = 2897
keycode 16, table 132 = 23
keycode 17, table 132 = 17
keycode 16, table 133 = 23
keycode 17, table 133 = 17
keycode 16, table 134 = 23
keycode 17, table 134 = 17
keycode 16, table 135 = 23
keycode 17, table 135 = 17
keycode 16, table 136 = 2167
keycode 17, table 136 = 2161
keycode 16, table 137 = 2135
keycode 17, table 137 = 2129
keycode 16, table 138 = 2167
keycode 17, table 138 = 2161
keycode 16, table 139 = 2135
keycode 17, table 139 = 2129
keycode 16, table 140 = 2071
keycode 17, table 140 = 2065
keycode 16, table 141 = 2071
keycode 17, table 141 = 2065
keycode 16, table 142 = 2071
keycode 17, table 142 = 2065
keycode 16, table 143 = 2071
keycode 17, table 143 = 2065
keycode 16, table 144 = 2935
keycode 17, table 144 = 2929
keycode 16, table 145 = 2903
keycode 17, table 145 = 2897
keycode 16, table 146 = 2935
keycode 17, table 146 = 2929
keycode 16, table 147 = 2903
keycode 17, table 147 = 2897
keycode 16, table 148 = 23
keycode 17, table 148 = 17
keycode 16, table 149 = 23
keycode 17, table 149 = 17
keycode 16, table 150 = 23
keycode 17, table 150 = 17
keycode 16, table 151 = 23
keycode 17, table 151 = 17
keycode 16, table 152 = 2167
keycode 17, table 152 = 2161
keycode 16, table 153 = 2135
keycode 17, table 153 = 2129
keycode 16, table 154 = 2167
keycode 17, table 154 = 2161
keycode 16, table 155 = 2135
keycode 17, table 155 = 2129
keycode 16, table 156 = 2071
keycode 17, table 156 = 2065
keycode 16, table 157 = 2071
keycode 17, table 157 = 2065
keycode 16, table 158 = 2071
keycode 17, table 158 = 2065
keycode 16, table 159 = 2071
keycode 17, table 159 = 2065
keycode 16, table 160 = 2935
keycode 17, table 160 = 2929
keycode 16, table 161 = 2903
keycode 17, table 161 = 2897
keycode 16, table 162 = 2935
keycode 17, table 162 = 2929
keycode 16, table 163 = 2903
keycode 17, table 163 = 2897
keycode 16, table 164 = 23
keycode 17, table 164 = 17
keycode 16, table 165 = 23
keycode 17, table 165 = 17
keycode 16, table 166 = 23
keycode 17, table 166 = 17
keycode 16, table 167 = 23
keycode 17, table 167 = 17
keycode 16, table 168 = 2167
keycode 17, table 168 = 2161
keycode 16, table 169 = 2135
keycode 17, table 169 = 2129
keycode 16, table 170 = 2167
keycode 17, table 170 = 2161
keycode 16, table 171 = 2135
keycode 17, table 171 = 2129
keycode 16, table 172 = 2071
keycode 17, table 172 = 2065
keycode 16, table 173 = 2071
keycode 17, table 173 = 2065
keycode 16, table 174 = 2071
keycode 17, table 174 = 2065
keycode 16, table 175 = 2071
keycode 17, table 175 = 2065
keycode 16, table 176 = 2935
keycode 17, table 176 = 2929
keycode 16, table 177 = 2903
keycode 17, table 177 = 2897
keycode 16, table 178 = 2935
keycode 17, table 178 = 2929
keycode 16, table 179 = 2903
keycode 17, table 179 = 2897
keycode 16, table 180 = 23
keycode 17, table 180 = 17
keycode 16, table 181 = 23
keycode 17, table 181 = 17
keycode 16, table 182 = 23
keycode 17, table 182 = 17
keycode 16, table 183 = 23
keycode 17, table 183 = 17
keycode 16, table 184 = 2167
keycode 17, table 184 = 2161
keycode 16, table 185 = 2135
keycode 17, table 185 = 2129
keycode 16, table 186 = 2167
keycode 17, table 186 = 2161
keycode 16, table 187 = 2135
keycode 17, table 187 = 2129
keycode 16, table 188 = 2071
keycode 17, table 188 = 2065
keycode 16, table 189 = 2071
keycode 17, table 189 = 2065
keycode 16, table 190 = 2071
keycode 17, table 190 = 2065
keycode 16, table 191 = 2071
keycode 17, table 191 = 2065
keycode 16, table 192 = 2935
keycode 17, table 192 = 2929
keycode 16, table 193 = 2903
keycode 17, table 193 = 2897
keycode 16, table 194 = 2935
keycode 17, table 194 = 2929
keycode 16, table 195 = 2903
keycode 17, table 195 = 2897
keycode 16, table 196 = 23
keycode 17, table 196 = 17
keycode 16, table 197 = 23
keycode 17, table 197 = 17
keycode 16, table 198 = 23
keycode 17, table 198 = 17
keycode 16, table 199 = 23
keycode 17, table 199 = 17
keycode 16, table 200 = 2167
keycode 17, table 200 = 2161
keycode 16, table 201 = 2135
keycode 17, table 201 = 2129
keycode 16, table 202 = 2167
keycode 17, table 202 = 2161
keycode 16, table 203 = 2135
keycode 17, table 203 = 2129
keycode 16, table 204 = 2071
keycode 17, table 204 = 2065
keycode 16, table 205 = 2071
keycode 17, table 205 = 2065
keycode 16, table 206 = 2071
keycode 17, table 206 = 2065
keycode 16, table 207 = 2071
keycode 17, table 207 = 2065
keycode 16, table 208 = 2935
keycode 17, table 208 = 2929
keycode 16, table 209 = 2903
keycode 17, table 209 = 2897
keycode 16, table 210 = 2935
keycode 17, table 210 = 2929
keycode 16, table 211 = 2903
keycode 17, table 211 = 2897
keycode 16, table 212 = 23
keycode 17, table 212 = 17
keycode 16, table 213 = 23
keycode 17, table 213 = 17
keycode 16, table 214 = 23
keycode 17, table 214 = 17
keycode 16, table 215 = 23
keycode 17, table 215 = 17
keycode 16, table 216 = 2167
keycode 17, table 216 = 2161
keycode 16, table 217 = 2135
keycode 17, table 217 = 2129
keycode 16, table 218 = 2167
keycode 17, table 218 = 2161
keycode 16, table 219 = 2135
keycode 17, table 219 = 2129
keycode 16, table 220 = 2071
keycode 17, table 220 = 2065
keycode 16, table 221 = 2071
keycode 17, table 221 = 2065
keycode 16, table 222 = 2071
keycode 17, table 222 = 2065
keycode 16, table 223 = 2071
keycode 17, table 223 = 2065
keycode 16, table 224 = 2935
keycode 17, table 224 = 2929
keycode 16, table 225 = 2903
keycode 17, table 225 = 2897
keycode 16, table 226 = 2935
keycode 17, table 226 = 2929
keycode 16, table 227 = 2903
keycode 17, table 227 = 2897
keycode 16, table 228 = 23
keycode 17, table 228 = 17
keycode 16, table 229 = 23
keycode 17, table 229 = 17
keycode 16, table 230 = 23
keycode 17, table 230 = 17
keycode 16, table 231 = 23
keycode 17, table 231 = 17
keycode 16, table 232 = 2167
keycode 17, table 232 = 2161
keycode 16, table 233 = 2135
keycode 17, table 233 = 2129
keycode 16, table 234 = 2167
keycode 17, table 234 = 2161
keycode 16, table 235 = 2135
keycode 17, table 235 = 2129
keycode 16, table 236 = 2071
keycode 17, table 236 = 2065
keycode 16, table 237 = 2071
keycode 17, table 237 = 2065
keycode 16, table 238 = 2071
keycode 17, table 238 = 2065
keycode 16, table 239 = 2071
keycode 17, table 239 = 2065
keycode 16, table 240 = 2935
keycode 17, table 240 = 2929
keycode 16, table 241 = 2903
keycode 17, table 241 = 2897
keycode 16, table 242 = 2935
keycode 17, table 242 = 2929
keycode 16, table 243 = 2903
keycode 17, table 243 = 2897
keycode 16, table 244 = 23
keycode 17, table 244 = 17
keycode 16, table 245 = 23
keycode 17, table 245 = 17
keycode 16, table 246 = 23
keycode 17, table 246 = 17
keycode 16, table 247 = 23
keycode 17, table 247 = 17
keycode 16, table 248 = 2167
keycode 17, table 248 = 2161
keycode 16, table 249 = 2135
keycode 17, table 249 = 2129
keycode 16, table 250 = 2167
keycode 17, table 250 = 2161
keycode 16, table 251 = 2135
keycode 17, table 251 = 2129
keycode 16, table 252 = 2071
keycode 17, table 252 = 2065
keycode 16, table 253 = 2071
keycode 17, table 253 = 2065
keycode 16, table 254 = 2071
keycode 17, table 254 = 2065
keycode 16, table 255 = 2071
keycode 17, table 255 = 2065

Changed 512 keys and 0 strings.
(No change in compose definitions.)
```

What can be failing? Is there any alternative to do this?

Comment: Which Linux distro and version are you using? (`loadkeys` works for me in Ubuntu, but only i text screens, not in terminal windows in X or Wayland desktop environments.)

Comment: @sudodus LxPupSc64 21.04 (PuppyLinux and LxDE, based on Slackware) with KBD package installed... It does not work for me or in the console nor in the terminal... If possible, I would like it to work before and after starting X.

Comment: I have only made short tests of Puppy (the latest test with BionicPup based on Ubuntu 18.04). I suggest that you ask someone who knows about Puppy Linux, for example [Mike Walsh](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/633850/puppy-linux-corner/page-34).

Comment: @sudodus I registered, but the following appears: `You cannot start a new topic`

Comment: Try to ask at [this thread](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/633850/puppy-linux-corner/page-34). Scroll to the end and 'Reply to that topic'.

Comment: Something similar happens to me. `You cannot reply to this topic`

Comment: I have a simple user ID there, and as you could see, I could write recently. I don't know what can be wrong there. Let us hope that Mike will see this soon and advice what to do, either directly or by suggesting a suitable forum.

Comment: @sudodus Oh, it's already, I had to activate the account. I think I'll start a new topic, so I do not deviate the theme.

Comment: OK. that's good :-)